mixing predictions and observations via a Credibility approach
Assume I have $p$ groups and want to predict a value $y$ based on the information from which group the observation was.
Let $y$ be the continuous response variable centered around $0$ and $X_1$,...,$X_p$ the $0$/$1$ regressors. Assume I use penalized regression (Ridge) to fit a GLM. If my understanding is correct, the penalisation would cause a shrinkage of the regression parameters towards $0$, just like a Bühlmann-Straub Credibility approach would (as the population mean is $0$).
So what would happen if I mixed the prediction coming from the GLM (i.e. scoring for $X_i=1$ for one $i$ in $[p]$, the rest being $0$) with the average value $y_i$ within that particular group using a Bühlmann-Straub approach? Could you think of any situation where doing this instead of just taking the "pure" model output can make sense?

Maybe you could tell us what a credibility approach is? and give a ref for Bühlmann-Straub approach?
